# Simulation of temperature sensor value in Packet Tracer no real hardware

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, temperature

I am using packet tracer to design a system, in the simulation I should emulate two Raspberry Pi's, but I cant get the first part to work where the first Pi should just get the value of the temperature sensor, I use python, but the value is not correct I dont know if there is a math for it to convert but I cant make it work

```
from gpio import *
from time import *

def main():
    pinMode(0, INPUT)
    while True:
        temp = analogRead(0);
        print(temp)
        delay(5000)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image to clarify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcnSd.png)

Comment: Do you have a simulation, or do you have real hardware? Where/how are you running this?

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes I am not using real hardware, using packet tracer I am 99% sure that I said that maybe I was unclear. Should I post an image to show or is it not needed ?